# When will Mathematica be added to the Elections site?

Tags: support, election-page

[Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) is a graduated site that has had an [election](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/election).

Why is it not on http://elections.stackexchange.com/, and when will it be added?

---

Eighteen months have passed and no reply.  Is the elections site currently maintained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be added the next time it has an election*. The site reads a network-wide list of meta posts looking for new elections and adds sites as it comes across them, since there's no way to get that information via the API.

> Eighteen months have passed and no reply

Uhh yeah. I remember having this question open in a tab a while ago and…never answered, for some reason. Sorry!

<sub>*But if you really have your heart set on it showing up, I can probably manually enter the data</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  No need for the data on my account.  I just want to make sure [Mathematica.SE] gets equal treatment. :-)

Comment: The problem is obviously that you're all too-effective moderators and haven't had a need for a new election this whole time! ;)

Comment: @TimStone Is it just me or is the elections site hacked? It is an interior design website for me https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5961318#5961318